# Is there any custom to thank the editor of a journal?

Tags: mathematics, peer-review

I am a PhD student in mathematics. Recently I received back a request for revision of an article I had submitted to a journal. The referee made several good suggestions; the chief editor also provided some suggestions.

When I resubmit the paper, it is natural I will thank to the referee. But **should I thank the editor as well**?

Comment: Minor language nitpick: most likely you did not receive "a revision of [your] article" but rather a message where you are asked to do a revision of your article.

Comment: @JochenGlueck, the chief editor mentioned in the first sentence that it is a (major) revision. They will decide about acceptance after the revision. But referee and the chief editor suggested several good points that will improve the paper. I understand their suggestions are good

Comment: Hmm, I'm under the impression that we're talking past each other. My comment is purely linguistic: It does not make sense to say that you "received a revision" because the word "revision" describes either the act of revising your article or the revised article itself. The editor did not send you a revision, they informed you about the decision that the journal requires a revision from you.

Comment: @JochenGlueck, ok, I understand.. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no reason why you should not thank anyone who has assisted you. Acknowledgements of this kind are often written in the third person, running on something like the following lines:

> The author would like to thank *two* anonymous reviewers and the journal *editor* for helpful remarks that significantly improved this paper.

... amend the italicised words as necessary!

Examples appear [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1475-4932.12441), [here](https://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1098&context=ajpl), [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/17577632.2022.2139570) and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167718716301369). In some of them, the editor is not only thanked, but named. The last of the four examples is almost identical to the words I have suggested above.

Comment: Thanks. It seems only one referee report was attached. The chief editor send an email. At first, he suggested on few good points about content and general aspects of the paper. Then he did paste the referee report below. Now I am not sure whether the suggestions given was from him or other editor. Since he sent the email, i suppose it is his suggestion. So the question is- should I write *chief editor* or just editor?

Comment: If you're asking here for a suggestion about wording (and I'm not sure whether you are), I'd err on the side of generosity. No one will be offended. Mention one (or two) reviewers as you see fit, and say "editors" (plural) even if you're unsure exactly who it (or they) might have been. The response from both your readers and from the people working at the journal, will be a brief bright thought in their day ... "Oh, that was nice!"

Comment: Yes. I understand it. I should use the word *editor* or *editors*.

Answer (score 2):

In normal circumstances, I would not thank the editor nor the reviewers in the body of the article itself (or any publicly-visible place - footnote, acknowledgements, etc.). I would, obviously, thank all around within the submission system, as is polite and customary to do (check your field’s cultural norms). It is entirely expected that any published article contains contributions from the editor(s) and reviewers.

In extraordinary circumstances, use context-specific judgement (and discuss with your coauthors if you have any). I have met such circumstances once in my career so far.

I was the junior author on a material science paper submitted to PNAS for which one of the reviews significantly generalized the theoretical result we presented (dropping certain convenient hypotheses and proving that the main results still held). The review was six pages long and included two figures. That is far from normal - the other review "merely" asked a few clarifications, pointed some errors, etc. (the standard stuff).

We ended up thanking "one referee for valuable suggestions relating to" that part of the paper. We did not thank the other referee (with the benefit of hindsight I would say their review was among the top 20% I ever received; never once did any of my senior coauthors suggest to thank them).

*To this day, I think that acknowledgement was insufficient. I think we should have proposed co-authorship to the reviewer, and if refused, made the acknowledgement much clearer about the scope of the contribution.*

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. It is interesting